# ElasticSearch - Creating multiple returns from a child array

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an object that looks roughly like this:

```
{
  "orderNumber": 1,
  "orderLines": [
    {
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "purchaseOrders": [
        {
          "poNumber": 1,
          "shipments": [
            {
              "shipmentNumber": 1,
              "late": "YES"
            },
            {
              "shipmentNumber": 2,
              "late": "YES"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "poNumber": 2,
          "shipments": [
            {
              "shipmentNumber": 1,
              "late": "YES"
            },
            {
              "shipmentNumber": 2,
              "late": "YES"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a nested query running that allows me to pull back the late shipments with the orderNumber. The result looks like this:

```
{
  "customer_order_number": "T391704031543",
  "order_lines": [
    {
      "order_line_number": "1",
      "order_line_type": "TEST",
      "purchase_orders": [
        {
          "purchase_order_number": "12344",
          "shipments": [
            {
              "shipment_number": 1,
              "shipment_status": "ALSO_NOT_SHIPPED",
              "tracking_events": [
                {
                  "event_date_time": "2023-09-17T09:03:17.000Z"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "shipment_number": 2,
              "shipment_status": "SHIP_IT_LIKE_YOU_MEAN_IT",
              "tracking_events": [
                {
                  "event_date_time": "2023-09-17T09:03:17.000Z"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "purchase_order_number": "12345",
          "shipments": [
            {
              "shipment_number": 1,
              "shipment_status": "SHIP_ME_HARDER",
              "tracking_events": [
                {
                  "event_date_time": "2023-09-17T09:03:17.000Z"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue I'm having is that I need a return like this:

```
orderNumber1->{orderLine1,{ purchaseOrder1, {shipmentNumber1}}}
orderNumber1->{orderLine1,{ purchaseOrder1, {shipmentNumber2}}}
orderNumber1->{orderLine1,{ purchaseOrder2, {shipmentNumber1}}}
orderNumber1->{orderLine1,{ purchaseOrder2, {shipmentNumber2}}}
```

Is this something that can be done from within the query?

I've tried parent/child query, I've worked with the 'fields' object, trying to work out how to create multiple lines from the single order_number, and am playing with the 'source' object. So far, no bueno.

Comment: You're trying to get relational database behavior from something completely different. Is switching to proper data model an option?

Comment: No, the record structure is what it is - it comes in from another process.

Comment: How does your query look like now? In your example, response is very different from sample record. Can you provide a full consistent example with mapping, sample data, query and results that you expect? At the moment, your question doesn't show that you really care about getting a good answer.

Comment: The structure of the data is pretty much what the first block has - only with quite a few more fields in each object. I'm trying to make sure I don't run afoul of posting anything that could cause me trouble.

The transfer array is 3 arrays deep- inside the orders array and the purchases array. My query just needs to check the status on the items in the transfer array, and return an object with the related fields.
The client needs a separate object for each transfer.

Comment: You don't have to post your company's data. You can create a fake example with fake data. At the moment it is really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve since your example response contains all information needed to build your desired result.

Comment: in that case, how would I go about building the listed response from that example response within the query? I feel like I'm missing some very minor, yet very fundamental part of the ElasticSearch process.

I apologize for being obtuse.